# link on the form title

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I add a clickable website link inside a window's form title?

Answer (score 4):

To make an area within the title bar clickable, you must override [`WndProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx) and handle [`WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645620.aspx)

In order to make it look like a link, you'll need to also handle `WM_NCPAINT` and `WM_NCMOUSEMOVE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
Technically, you can, if you draw the window chrome yourself, but you *reallly* shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the form code and draw the title yourself (you set `FormBorderStyle` property to none, create a `TextBox`, etc). There's no build-in mechanism for this in .NET framework.